# Lenovo Legion PXI-E61 Media Test Failure, Check Cable. Exiting PXE ROM. Then restarts and works fine

Tags: boot, lenovo, pxe

[image]After a series of unfortunate events, I was finally able to install ubuntu 19.04 in my Lenovo Legion Y530. I had to install the OS for like 10 times after erasing the last ubuntu installation again and again. (after erasing the preinstalled windows 10 for the first time) and in Legacy Mode. Now the problem I am facing is the following:

*When I start the machine, after displaying Legion logo, the following message comes*:

```
Intel UNDI , PXE 2.1 ....Realtek PCIe GBE family controller series v2.66...
PXE-E61: Media Test Failure, check cable. PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
```

**After that, it shuts down, starts again and loads ubuntu properly**

Specs:

- Lenovo Legion Y530
- No dual boot
- HDD
- 8GB RAM
- 4GB NVIDIA GeForce 1050
- Legacy Mode

Comment: *...and in Legacy Mode* well, this is wrong. UEFI machines should be installed in UEFI mode. However, this isn't related to the message. That is because you have PXE boot higher in the boot order.

Comment: I have changed the boot menu. In EFI, ubuntu is higher. In Legacy, HDD is higher. Also I tried installing it in UEFI for 6 times, but after each installation, when it prompted to restart, the laptop froze for hours. Then I tried legacy. @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Doing things that are over our heads often result in headaches :) For your laptop it should be UEFI mode and, because Nvidia graphics, Secure boot disabled. Then, if the graphical environment doesn't boot correctly, we use `nomodeset` as a boot parameter to boot in low graphics mode that allow the installation of the required Nvidia drivers, after that it should boot normally and smoothly. Now that you installed in Legacy perhaps better to disable UEFI as the legacy boot is what matters and, again, somehow you must have select PXE (network) boot in Legacy. >>>

Comment: >>> But because as you say you *had to install the OS for like 10 times* it's probably now so f... screwed up that it's anyone's guess why it tries to boot from network first.

Comment: I installed it in UEFi with secure boot disabled. That worked fine when windows was also installed sidewise. Then I erased windows and installed ubuntu only in UEFI. The grub menu for setting nouveau modeset=0 never came up after I set it for the first time in Try ubuntu without installing. The laptop froze each time. I have disabled UEFI already. @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: So is there a way that I can make HDD fresh for a new clean installation. I already tried **sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress**

Comment: We press ESC or SHIFT for making the Grub menu appear after installing ;) There's no point in zeroing the drive in your case, it's a waste of time and wears it out unnecessarily. If you want you can install over and optionally, in a live session, use GParted to delete the whole drive, also create the correct partition table for the installation type -> GPT for UEFI, MBR for BIOS/Legacy. All this before actually installing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I will try these. @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: You may need this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu and remeber to install the recommended Nvidia drivers version that you'll find in Additional Drivers.

Comment: The answer below should be anything you need. I wasn't even aware of the potential issue with the WiFi. Please remember to accept it in order to properly reward the amazing effort by @heynnema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re: "*PXE-E61: Media Test Failure, check cable. PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.*"

The Preboot Execution Environment (PXE) is an industry standard client/server interface that allows networked computers that are not yet loaded with an operating system to be configured and booted remotely by an administrator.

This means that your BIOS boot order is incorrect. If you look at the current boot order setting, you'll find that PXE boot comes before CD/DVD and HDD/SSD.

Your boot order should look something like:

1. CD/DVD
2. HDD/SSD
3. USB
4. PXE

**Update #1:**

Your boot mode/priority AND your SATA controller should NOT be set to legacy. Secure Boot and Fast Boot should be disabled.

**Update #2:**

Check your BIOS version, and update if required. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Open `terminal`. Type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a BIOS update.

To update your BIOS, and since Windows is no longer installed, see https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Legion-Y530-15ICH-Laptop-Bios-Update-with-Linux/td-p/4342841

**Update #3:**

To properly install Ubuntu on this laptop, see https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops-Knowledge-Base/Installing-Ubuntu-18-xx-on-the-Legion-Y530/ta-p/4187251

Partial clip...

Step 11: Select "try ubuntu without installing" or equivalent option

Step 12: Once on the desktop has booted, open a terminal and run sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop to allow wifi to work then follow the ubuntu steps for installing the OS

Step 13: Follow the instructions for rebooting after the install has completed. after the legion screen, but before the boot screen, press escape to get to the grub selection menu.

Step 14: press e on the option for your OS, and edit the "quiet splash" line to "quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"  once the nvidia drivers are installed, this won't be needed

Step 15: Press F10 to boot the OS, once you are at the desktop, open the terminal and run sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop

Step 16: without closing the terminal Perform a system update (e.g sudo apt-update && sudo apt dist-upgrade for ubuntu)

Step 17: run the command sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Step 18: add blacklist ideapad_laptop to the end of the file, this will get wifi working permanently

Comment: Yes, exactly. But OP insists that in Legacy the HDD is higher, cf. comments above.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can't upvote twice. I would if I could :) However, I would change step #16 to ... `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia and I added Update #2...

Comment: Very good suggestion.

Comment: I have tried each and every step of the above mentioned process from the same post. It still poses a lot of problems. I have added the current boot menu image in updated post. @heynnema

Comment: @NeeravKaushal Your boot mode/priority AND your SATA controller should NOT be set to legacy. Secure Boot and Fast Boot should be disabled. Have you checked your BIOS version, as I specify?

Comment: Also due to these exact same steps, I am able to run ubuntu properly right now. @heynnema

Comment: Sure @heynnema. I have just upgraded my bios and will try to install ubuntu again. Will remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot @heynnema and GabrielaGarcia.  ALL THE PROBLEMS WERE SOLVED WHEN I UPDATED THE BIOS. I installed windows and updated BIOS. Then erased it and installed ubuntu. There was no need of modeset, quite splash etc. because ubuntu detected nvidia itself in additional drivers. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It's fixed with my Update #2